# conversion of Cartesian to spherical

Tags: trigonometry

$$(x,y,z) = (-0.000088,-0.180976,0.930832)$$

For finding $\theta$ I'm using the conversion formula 
$\theta = \tan^{-1} \dfrac{y}{x}$
I'm getting a value of $1.57031007451$ radians ($89$ degrees).

But an online converter of Cartesian to spherical coordinates gives me negative result

**($\theta = -89$ degrees)**

Am I missing something?

Comment: yeah its correct

Comment: -89 in 4th quadrant and 89 in first. Is that what u were asking ?

Comment: I'm getting incorrect values for the same formula in my python script. But this makes sense, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All answers you got are incorrect because you were indifferent to sign of x- and y-.

If both x and y are negative the angle terminates in the third quadrant. With respect to relative magnitudes of x and y in clockwise direction it should be a bit less than 270 degrees, in counter-clockwise direction it should be a bit more than 90 degrees,

There are *two types* of arctan function. The one does not give attention to quadrant, and one fixes quadrant correctly.

In Mathematica the latter angle in degrees  is:

ArcTan[-.0000088, -.180976] * $180/ \pi$ =  -90.0028

BTW it is same for spherical or cylindrical coordinates because you are not involving z coordinate.

Comment: This worked! I used the atan2 function in python instead of atan. atan2 uses -pi to pi as the range , now my angles are right! Thank you so much!

Comment: Fine if it works. A few including here are well to recognize the good old atan2 FORTRAN function.